# How do I manage my Redis cache best using PHP?

Tags: redis

we two Redis servers 1379 and 1380. Both have 3 databases (via Magento).

What is the best php software to manage these databases? 
View size, data, flush, monitor etc

We have tried phpredisadmin. But it does not show per database & cannot flush

**Any advice appreciated**

Comment: You may want to try out Redsmin ( https://redsmin.com ), it's cross-plateform and provide monitoring, data-visualization and administration for Redis.

Comment: Sounds great. We run Centos - does the proxy work there too? Maybe you want to add this to answer. Looks pretty cool. Just sent you an email to get it to work

Comment: Yes, the proxy should work on Centos on too! Check out: http://redsmin.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/121169-can-i-manage-redis-instances-only-accessible-from-